# Cross Correlation of Two Signal to Calculate Delay

Tags: matlab, fft, cross-correlation

I am working on the cross-correlation of two signals to calculate delay. But somehow, I could not calculate the delay correctly.

i1, i2, and ti1: [data link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/26e5b4dfabe9311f256c81c7ca31055a20220613134946/dd60675664ba435676cb66f0cd1328ed20220613134947/f2dd92)

here is code:

```
t = ti1; % 1x2097152 double
t_Step = t(2)-t(1);
t_tmp = [-flip(t(2:end)),t];
x = i1; %1x2097152 complex double
y = i2; % 1x2097152 complex double
corrL=length(x)+length(y)-1;

X=fft(x,corrL); % FFT of x
Y=fft(y,corrL); % FFT of y

Z=X.*(conj(Y)); % Hadamard Product/ frequeny domain
z=fftshift(ifft(Z)); % time domain convertion

Ly=length(z);
tz= t_tmp;

[~,idz] = max(z) % find the index at max point of z
TD = tz(idz)*t_Step      % Time Delay

if(TD<0)
distance = -TD * 204357.1915 % speed of light in specific indise is 204357.1915 distance calculation
else(TD<0)
distance = TD * 204357.1915
end
%Plot Section
%Original and delayed signal
plot(t,x,'r',t,y,'g'); 
legend('Original','Delayed');
%Cross Correlated Signal
[z_max, index] = max(imag(z))
figure
%plot(tz,z,tz(index),y(index),'o'); hold on
plot(tz,z,tz(index),z_max,'o')

xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Magnitude');
title('z signal');
grid
```

Here is the marked signal which puts the mark in the wrong place:

[image]

I was expected to put the mark at the max amplitude point, so somehow I could not put the mark at the extremum point of amplitude. Could you help me to fix that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. Could you please [edit] the post to clarify what went wrong? Is the "mark" the little circle at `(-0.5, 1.6)`? Why do you think it is false and where do you think it should be? If you think there's a *programming* mistake, please [edit] the question to contain (sample) data, such that we can run it. If, on the other hand, the problem is of a theoretical nature, you might get better help over at [stats.SE].

Comment: @Adriaan, thank you for your comment. I have tried to fix my question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for updating the image. Please add a sample of the data into the question itself, rather than an off-site link (especially one to wetransfer, which will go offline in a week). As to your question: did you happen to get a warning "Imaginary parts are ignored" for the plotting? Probably you mean `max(real(z))`, as MATLAB plots the real part by default. Otherwise, `plot(tz, imag(z)` will have its peak there. All in all: the amplitude is given by `abs(z)`, i.e. `plot(tz, abs(z))` and use `max(abs(z))`.

Comment: @Adriaan, thank you for your help. I will consider adding input sample code to the question later. As you can see in the code, I tried to cross-correlate two signals to calculate the delay. Somehow the results are not proper as I expected (I did delay for 100km which I expected around 100 km/204357.1915 km/s (speed of light) = 0.00048933927534 us delay ). Could you suggest anything about this?